# angular stream content to user file system

Tags: angular, blob

We have an angular application on client side.
I want to offload my report file preparation from server to client. 
We create CSV file on server which can be around 300MB and give link for download from client browser.

Now I want to receive these data from server into my angular application some 5K rows at a time and keep writing the content in stream fashion into client file system. The angular application should not holddata and write one shot.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453509/how-to-perform-stream-in-angular-on-file-without-storing-in-browser-memory